# JSON file to List of Object keeps throwing error not subtype of specific object type

Tags: flutter

I am trying to conver JSON file to List so I can use it with DropdownMenuItem. The method stops whenever I am trying to decode the response and throws this error: `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Country>'` How can I solve this??

method:

```dart
List<Country> _countryList = [];

  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/countries.json');
    print(response);
    final List<Country> data = await json.decode(response).map((e) => Country.fromJson(e)).toList();

    setState(() {
      _countryList = data;
    });
  }
```

My Json looks like this

```json
[
 {
     "value": "AFG",
     "label": "Afghanistan",
     "eu": false
},
....
]
```

Country model class

```dart
class Country {
  String value;
  String label;
  bool eu;

  Country({
    required this.value,
    required this.label,
    required this.eu,
  });

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Country(
      value: json["value"],
      label: json["label"],
      eu: json["eu"],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing this `.map((e) => Country.fromJson(e))` to this `.map<Country>((e) => Country.fromJson(e))` and seeing if it works?

Comment: @h8moss thanks, worked.

Answer (score 0):

`json.decode(..)` returns `dynamic` type and in your case you need to cast it to `List`

```dart
  final decodedJson = jsonDecode(response) as List;
```

now take the `decodedJson` and cast its generic type

```dart
  final castedList = decodedJson.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

now it will be so simple to map it to dart object `Country`

```dart
  final List<Country> data = castedList.map((e) => Country.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

the final result:

```dart
List<Country> _countryList = [];

  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/countries.json');
    print(response);
  final decodedJson = jsonDecode(response) as List;
  final castedList = decodedJson.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  final List<Country> data =
       castedList.map((e) => Country.fromJson(e)).toList();

    setState(() {
      _countryList = data;
    });
  }
```